# What are the financial benefits for a company to give out student scholarships?

Tags: tax-deduction, scholarship

I have been trying to figure out why a company would spend €100K - €200K on student scholarships.

I just can't seem to figure it out.

Is there any financial benefit through tax exemptions?

Can more money be hidde in such a way?

For this scenario, let's say that there is definitely an ulterior motive and by no means does the company simply want to contribute to society and empower local youth.

Comment: Often if you accept such a scholarship you need to work for the company for a period after graduation or else pay back the scholarship. You just need to read the terms of the scholarship to find out, it's usually pretty explicit.

Comment: How is this question connected to personal finance?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about Personal Finance.

Comment: @RobertLongson What is written in the agreement is not the actual reason, this is why I'm asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a business spends money they don't have to, they do it for one the the following reasons:

- It will reduce their taxes. While the tax break is always less than the expense reducing your taxes makes the expense less painful
- They hopefully can leverage the  cost now into future income. If they also require an internship from the recipients they do get some work done for the cost of the scholarship and the wages.
- They can use it to show the community that they are a good company. Local scholarships are a great way to do this. They can them remind everybody about their support of the local community when they need the government to approve the new factory.
- they can advertise the scholarships at job fairs.
- they can mention them when trying to bid on new contracts.

It doesn't have to be scholarships; they also sponsor community cleanups, shred events, the local hospital, youth sports programs...

Comment: Personally I would reorder the list, with tax benefit at the bottom - it is a common assumption that such things provide net overall benefit, when it is simpler to just say 'all charitable work by a for-profit company is advertising, which possibly aligns with the personal goals of those who have the power to make decisions within the company'.

Comment: You missed an important motivation, which is to attract employees who want to improve their education and are capable of it.

Comment: Tax cuts sounds right